# How to use commandline parameters in LibGDX

Tags: java, gwt, libgdx

I searched up and down and did not find any solution for the following problem.

I have a LibGDX app which communicates with a server over a REST-like API. Since I want to deploy it I need a way to specify the host address of the API-server with either a build parameter or a runtime argument/parameter (since I want to use localhost as the API-server in development). I mainly need it for HTML and Desktop. If it works on other platforms, it would be appreciated. I tried a few different things:

- adding a `-DpropertyName=value` flag to the deploying Tomcat Container and using `System.getProperty("propertyName")` in code obviously doesn't work because at the point where the code is in Tomcat it was already entirely processed by GWT. I even got an Error by GWT: `Property 'propertyName' is not defined.` which led me to:
- adding a property definition to the `GdxDefinition.gwt.xml` like follows:

  ```
  <define-property name="propertyName" values="value,otherValue"/>
  <set-property name="propertyName" value="value"/>
  ```

  removes the error and compiles the app successfully. The `System.getProperty("propertyName")` picks up the value `value` and GWT only compiles the following only with the `value` branch. (I found no mention of the second URL in the compiled code in the dist directory but only the first URL)

  ```
  switch (System.getProperty("propertyName")) {
      case "value":
          HOST_ADDRESS = "https://my.domain.me/api";
          break;
      case "otherValue":
          HOST_ADDRESS = "http://localhost:8080/api";
          break;
      default:
          throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + System.getProperty("propertyName"));
  }
  ```

  Therefore I guess I have to specifiy the property value as a compiler argument. For GWT it would be `-setProperty propertyName=otherValue`. But how can I pass it when I build the webapp with gradle `./gradlew html:dist`. `-DpropertyName=otherValue` doesn't work.

Do you have any idea how I get this approach work, or do you have another method? Maven has some kind of `${propertyName}` method to set Maven properties in config files. Is this possible in Gradle too?

Comment: Is your app a static html or you can generate host page on some kind of server side (e.g tomcat, jetty)?

Comment: @AlexanderLeshkin It is a [LibGDX](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) Application. In this framework you write common code in Java and then compile it to different platforms. The transformation to HTML is done using [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/). My problem I guess is, that the GWT Gradle Plugin doesn't support -setProperty flag of GWT.

Comment: Seems that you are right and setProperty is not available in this gradle plugin. As an option you can define configuration property in the GdxDefinition.gwt.xml and override it in GdxDefinitionSuperdev.gwt.xml (this one is used in devmode only). Also you may try to use different host pages for dev and prod modes and define configuration directly in host page.